# Showing that a set is a orientable manifold

Tags: analysis, manifolds

So I was trying to show that if $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $C^1$ function, and $c$ is a regular value , i.e,$\nabla f(x)\neq 0$, for all $x\in f^{-1}(c)$, then $f^{-1}([c,\infty))$ is a orientable manifold with boundary.

I do know that it holds if I consider the manifold $M=f^{-1}(c)$, but I'm not able to generalize to this case the same argument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint, break the problem into steps:

1. $M=f^{-1}[c,+\infty)$ is an $n$-dimensional submanifold with boundary (whose boundary is $f^{-1}(c)$);
2. Every $n$-dimensional submanifold with boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orientable.